# golang is there an easy way to unmarshal arbitrary complex json

Tags: go

Every example I come to online shows examples of building structs for the data and then unmarshaling JSON into the data type. The problem is that what I am getting is massive dump of JSON and it seems like backbreaking labor to use such a method....

Is there a way to take a huge dump of data and get it to unmarshal into a map like object that would function similar to json/maps?

What I have right now is like this...

```
var data map[interface{}]interface{}
err = json.Unmarshal(JSONDUMP, &data)
if err != nil { log.Fatal(err) }
```

but then I cannot call it like this

```
data["some"]["long"]["chain"]["of"]["lookups"] 
(type interface {} does not support indexing)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In general this is a **bad** idea! But if you really need, you can do like this:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var anyJson map[string]interface{}

    customJSON := []byte(`{"a": "text comes here", "b": {"c":10, "d": "more text"}}`)

    json.Unmarshal(customJSON, &anyJson)

    fmt.Println("a ==", anyJson["a"].(string))

    b_temp := anyJson["b"].(map[string]interface{})
    fmt.Println("c ==", b_temp["c"].(float64))
}
```

.. then you can use any field like `anyJson["a"].(string)` - look at type assertion, it's critically important to be valid

Comment: 1. why is it a bad idea? 2. what would be the other options besides making a giant struct?

Comment: @deltaskelta It's a bad idea since you forgo type safety that concrete types provide.

Comment: @deltaskelta, for example, your program will just crash if in some field you expect **int**, but suddenly receive **string**. How big is "giant"? Even 100 fields are not so bad, you need to define them only once

Comment: What if my json is: {"arbitrary_name":[...]}. I am unable to unmarshal it this way.

Comment: @svobol13, still works for me. `anyJson["arbitrary_name"].([]interface{}))` - try to access it like a slice of interfaces. Probably unmarshaller doesn't try to guess the types inside a slice

Comment: To avoid crashes if the types aren't as expected, just use the safe form of type assertion: `if i, ok := x.(int); ok {`.  If you know the type, use the type!  But if not, this works.

Answer (score 13):

You can use third party libraries such as [`gabs`](https://github.com/Jeffail/gabs) or [`jason`](https://github.com/antonholmquist/jason).

```
data := []byte(`{
    "outter":{
        "inner":{
            "value1":"test"
        }
     }`)
```

Gabs :

```
jsonParsed, err := gabs.ParseJSON(data)
value, ok = jsonParsed.Path("outter.inner.value1").Data().(string)
```

Jason :

```
v, _ := jason.NewObjectFromBytes(data)
value, _ := v.GetString("outter","inner","value1")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to parse arbitrary objects you can do this using the standard `encoding/json` library:

```
func ParseAnyJSON(data string) (any, error) {
    var object any
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &object)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return object, nil
}
```