# Is there any way to extract JSON Schema from a given JSON in Go?

Tags: json, go, jsonschema, data-conversion

Is there a way that to convert a JSON to its schema in Go? I need to compare 2 JSON templates or schemas and cannot find any package or function to do the same - can someone please help me with this?

Comment: you must unmarshal your json templates to interface and then compare that.

Comment: I don't know my template format beforehand so cannot define a structure or interface. I just have any 2 JSON's and need to extract their templates and compare them.

Comment: Please do not post the same question again if the original one has been closed. If you think it was closed by mistake, please feel free to bring it up with the SO moderators. (In this particular case, the question was [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the sole comment to it nevertheless suggested a working solution.)

Comment: To expand on this on-topic/off-topic thing a bit further, SO is not the sole resource one may use to ask questions about programming topics, and _its format_ presupposes certain approach to asking questions. If/when your question does not fit this format, that's OK but you ought to use another communication venue to ask it. In the case of the Go programming language, such alternative venues are listed [here](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki#the-go-community). I would presonally pick the mailing list, but as usually, YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at [gjson library](http://github.com/tidwall/gjson). It has functions to parse and get unmarshalled JSON. You can use `gjson` functionality to compare json results.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need to `unmarshal` them recursively (if they contain nested json) into something like `map[string]interface{}`, and then loop through and compare the keys. There are some libraries mentioned on this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/42153666 which could be used to `unmarshal` them safely.

For example, You can use `Exists` from the gabs library while iterating through the keys in the unmarhsalled map to see if the same keys exist in the other map.

```
// From gabs library
// Exists checks whether a field exists within the hierarchy.
func (g *Container) Exists(hierarchy ...string) bool {
    return g.Search(hierarchy...) != nil
}
```

Edit: without libraries here: https://play.golang.org/p/jmfFsLT0G1n based on the test case of this code golf exercise: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/195476/extract-all-keys-from-an-object-json

Comment: but the structure of my JSON can be anything which I do not know beforehand, so I may or may not have nested json - how will I write code for that? Like how would I know when to move recursively inside the nested structure and by how much?

Comment: If you were to write the functionality yourself you would need to check by recursively using `Unmarshal` and catch any errors (e.g. when the `interface{}` part of the `map[string]interface{}` result, is either a string, boolean or a number of some sort). **But** if you use the gabs library you won't need to check for nested structures. The library will do that for you and you can just compare the keys of the results.

Answer (score -1):

The json package provided in Go’s standard library provides us with all the functionality we need. For any JSON string, the standard way to parse it is:

```
import "encoding/json" //...

// ...  myJsonString := `{"some":"json"}`

// `&myStoredVariable` is the address of the variable we want to store our // parsed data in 
json.Unmarshal([]byte(myJsonString), &myStoredVariable)

 //...
```

Comment: This will convert my JSON to a Go var or struct whose schema i know before hand - for eg. in:
'''func main() {
 var jsonBlob = []byte(`[
 {"Name": "Platypus", "Order": "Monotremata"},
 {"Name": "Quoll",    "Order": "Dasyuromorphia"}
]`)
 type Animal struct {
  Name  string
  Order string
 }
 var animals []Animal
 err := json.Unmarshal(jsonBlob, &animals)
 if err != nil {
  fmt.Println("error:", err)
 }
 fmt.Printf("%+v", animals)
}'''
we know the exact struct of Animal before, but I want to write a tool to compare any 2 JSON schemas so I can't use Unmarshal for the same.